# Should "De là à dire/penser que ..." be followed by a verb in the indicative, subjunctive, or conditional mood?

Tags: temps-grammatical

> Il s'est avéré que nos mots de passe sur Facebook étaient loin d'être aussi sécurisés qu'on le laisse croire. **De là à dire/penser qu**'ils **ont** aussi pour habitude de lire nos textos privés dans notre dos, il n'y a qu'un pas.

I was just writing a comment on another forum, and I'm left wondering which mood goes well with the subordinate clause of "*De là à dire/penser que ...*":

> **De là à dire/penser qu**'ils **aient** aussi pour habitude de lire nos textos privés dans notre dos, il n'y a qu'un pas.
>
> **De là à dire/penser qu**'ils **auraient** aussi pour habitude de lire nos textos privés dans notre dos, il n'y a qu'un pas.

The conditional mood (used for speculation and hearsay) seems least likely in a subordinate clause, but for the sake of argument.

Answer (score 1):

Any mood or tense might follow *que* here:

> *De là à dire qu'ils **ont, ont eu, avaient, avaient eu, eurent, eurent eu, auront, auront eu, aient, aient eu, eussent, eussent eu, auraient, auraient eu** aussi pour habitude de lire...*

The one to use depends on what you actually had in mind.

Stephane's comment summarize very well the rules:

*As to which form should be chosen, in a few words, if the thought statement is viewed as a thesis you'd use indicative, if it's viewed as a hypothesis you'd use subjunctive, and if it's viewed as an eventuality, you'd use conditional.*

Comment: As to which form should be chosen, in a few words, if the thought statement is viewed as a thesis you'd use indicative, if it's viewed as a hypothesis you'd use subjuctive, and if it's viewed as an eventuality, you'd use conditionnal.

Answer (score 0):

"aient" is subjective and "auraient" is at the conditional. You use them depending of your sentence.

In your particular sentence I think I will use the indicative "ont"

[Verbes d'opinion +subjonctif ou indicatif - cours](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-93819.php)